# How to use an 2-axis accelerometer as a potentiometer?

Tags: pwm, resistance, potentiometer, dac, accelerometer

I've got a couple of [Memsic 2125 accelerometers](https://www.parallax.com/sites/default/files/downloads/28017-Memsic-MXD2125-Datasheet.pdf) around and wanted to try to use one of them to replace a pair of potentiometers in a circuit (x axis replaces pot A, y axis replaces pot B).

How would I go about converting the output signal of the accelerometer into resistance? Along with that, how would I limit the resistance to a particular range?

(Apologies if this is a rather basic question - I'm a tinkerer and am pretty early on in my EE journey!)

EDIT: Added from comments per gbulmer's suggestion:

So the application will be a guitar pedal or something like it, so let's try with something simple. Say using just the x axis to control the fuzz pot in a simple NPN fuzz face.

[image: NPN Fuzz Face schematic]

Comment: There's no nice way to do that... if you truly need a resistor you would probably need a microcontroller to read the accelerometer, and then transfer the value scaled/constrained value to a digipot.  It probably makes sense to step back and look at better ways of solving your actual problem than using these.

Comment: Often potentiometers are used as voltage dividers to provide an anjustable voltage. In that case, replacing them with accelerometers should be straightforward, but you need to provide more information on the circuit that contains the potentiometers. As Chris has said, your question should be "how do I replace the potentiometers' functionality in this particular circuit?".

Comment: So the application will be a guitar pedal or something like it, so let's try with something simple. Say using just the x axis to control the fuzz pot in a simple NPN fuzz face. Image of schematic here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/PKVQB.gif

Comment: It'd help the community if you updated the question with the extra information (e.g. schematic) from your comment rather than leave parts of the question in comments. As the list of comments grows, your comments might not be visible, and it helps everyone if all of the facts are in the body of the question.

Answer (score 1):

A quick-n-dirty way would be to convert your accelerometer's digital outputs to analog as shown in the data sheet at the bottom of page 5. Then you could use that voltage to inject current into an ordinary transistor (like 2N2222, et.al.)  That would cause the transistor to conduct more or less current depending on the voltage/current going into the base of the transistor. You could replace that 1K ohm "Fuzz" pot with your accelerometer-controlled transistor.

The volume control would be a bit more tricky.  But you could use a similar "shunt" circuit to "short out" more or less of the audio output signal with another transistor connected like the "Fuzz" circuit.

A more proper method would be to use the digital outputs from the accelerometer into a microcontroller (Arduino, et.al.) and then use the microcontroller to control a couple of digital potentiometers which could be directly substituted in your circuit.

Comment: Is there an IC that I could use - even if I had to use 1 per output?

Comment: As I mentioned, there are digital pots which exactly perform that function. But the output from your accelerometer is not directly compatible with digital pots. Which is why you need something inbetween. Either the quick-n-dirty "DAC" and transistor scheme or the proper microcontroller solution.

Comment: Note that a "microcontroller" could be something as small as an 8-pin DIP IC. There are 8-pin variants of the "Arduino" scheme that may be just what you need for a project like this.  For example: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9378

Comment: Thanks Richard. I think I phrased my followup poorly - I meant if there was an IC you know of that already would have that functionality - I don't really know anything about programming ICs.

Comment: It isn't that difficult. Even primary-school children are doing it every day.  OTOH, Google returned About 38,800 results (0.55 seconds) when I searched for: accelerometer guitar pedal